# Removing/Hiding Review tab on product pages

Tags: magento2.2.4, review, tabs

I'm trying to remove the **review tab** that appears on product pages and I have added in the two reference blocks below in `catalog_product_view.xml`.

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.review" template="product/view/review.phtml"/>
<referenceBlock name="product.info.review" remove="true" />
<referenceBlock name="reviews.tab" remove="true" />
```

However this has not just **removed the review** tab but also **the Description** and **Additional Information** Tabs. Is there a way of just removing the review tab and nothing else?

My **Magento version is 2.2.4**

Answer (score 1):

> app/code/Vendor/YourTheme/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <referenceBlock name="reviews.tab" remove="true"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: This does the same of removing all tabs rather than just the reviews tab. Is there a way to differentiate between the tabs so you only remove one?

Comment: This code removing only review tab only, not whole. This code working fine with M2.3